# asp.net mvc: Connect buttons to new page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Right now when user clicks button SARU, the method `AddGroupSARU` is called. Now I want to go to page `Layout.cshtml`, so when user clicks the button, `Layout.cshtml` is opened.

```
 <button id="SARU" class="btn btn-inverse btn-large">
                        SARU</button>
                    <div class="span1">
                        <button id="AN" class="btn btn-inverse :hover btn-large">
                            AN</button>
                              <script type="text/javascript">
                              $(function(){

                                $('#SARU').click(function () {
                                   $.post("@Url.Action("AddGroupSARU","User")");
                                  });
                                 });
                         </script>
                    </div>
```

`@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml")` renders the Layout at the bottom of the Button page while I want to go to `Layout.cshtml` page with clicking the button.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the role of Layouts. Have a look at this http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx

Comment: I have multiple layout and I want to render one of them by clicking this button

Comment: You cannot render a Layout by itself. You can render a view which uses layout file.